# Why is this showing? mysqli_query(): Empty query in /home/evansbwg/public_html/Old Things/Website/insert.php on line 52

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
//$game_id = ['gameid'];
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$postal_code = $_POST['postalcode'];
$start_date = $_POST['startdate'];
$rental_days = $_POST['rentaldays'];
$borrow_game = $_POST['borrowgame'];
```

Variables are set here^!

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date.' + '.$rental_days.'days'));
```

How the end_date function works^!

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "evansbwg_user", "1password1", "evansbwg_database");

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Connection^!

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_games WHERE game_name = '$borrow_game'");

//$result_present = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows == 1)

{
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $id = $row2['game_id'];
```

Getting game_id to equal borrow_game^!

```
    $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM tbl_rental WHERE game_id = '$id' 
    AND (start_date <= '$start_date' AND end_date >= '$end_date')
    OR (start_date >= '$start_date' AND start_date <= '$end_date')
    OR (end_date >= '$start_date' AND end_date <= '$end_date')
    OR (start_date >= '$start_date' AND end_date <= '$end_date')";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_search);

    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

    if ($num == 0) 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_rental (game_id, first_name, last_name, address, postal_code, start_date, rental_days, borrow_game, end_date)
       VALUE ('$id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$address', '$postal_code', '$start_date', '$rental_days', '$borrow_game', '$end_date')";
```

Inserting the data into the table^!

```
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    }

}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $id = $row['game_id'];
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I have fixed my main problem however if any changes need to be made please suggest.

Comment: you mean to say connection code is not working?

Comment: @Halcyon The if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)).

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /home/evansbwg/public_html/Old Things/Website/insert.php on line 52

Comment: You only set `$sql` if `$num` is 0, but use it even if it is <> 0. `$sql` is empty in this case.

Comment: @RolandJansen how do I fix that, do i remove if $num = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happen if

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
```

Return `than more than one zero row`

```
if ($num == 0)
```

You code not enter into `if condition` and your `$sql variable is empty`

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))// here $sql is empty if $num is greater then zero
```

So close proper your if condition

```
if ($num == 0) 
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_rental (game_id, first_name, last_name, address, postal_code, start_date, rental_days, borrow_game, end_date)
VALUE ('$id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$address', '$postal_code', '$start_date', '$rental_days', '$borrow_game', '$end_date')";

Inserting the data into the table^!

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
echo "New record created successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}// if condition close here
```

Also connection close at the end of your code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$id = $row['game_id'];
}

mysqli_close($conn);// at last
```

Answer (score 2):

You closed your connection prematurely, so the query following that has no connection to the query.

```
mysqli_close($conn);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$id = $row['game_id'];
}
```

place it at the end of your script or just remove it.

Also this line makes no sense `$end_date = ['enddate'];`

You probably meant to do:

```
$end_date = $_POST['enddate'];
```

since the others above that are using POST arrays.

However, seeing

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date.' + '.$rental_days.'days'));
```

You would need to remove `$end_date = ['enddate'];`, that's invalid syntax.

---

Sidenote:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also, add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.